# Loading Spinner Gif

Tags: gimp, gif

I would like to create a loading spinner that looks like the one GitHub uses:

[image]

Any tips on how to replicate this with another logo inside using Gimp? I am especially interested in this "interrupted" border structure. I have no clue how to do that :(

Comment: Hi user3376954, what part are you having trouble with specifically (As in making the design itself or creating the animation part)? Can you describe what you have tried?

Comment: I would start creating a circle, but I have no idea how to seperate it like the one in the picture. The second specific question would be how many frames do I need? One for each filled border-partial?

Comment: Sounds like you need to start with something more basic, and get more proficient with the software. Otherwise I feel like you'll need a step-by-step tutorial which isn't what this site is for.

Comment: Is there no way to describe how to seperate a circle into partials of equal size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing this in Photoshop but the process would be the same in GIMP.

Create a circle

Create the divider line. This will be used to subtract from the circle.

[image: circle]

I then duplicated the layer and rotated the object. In total this is 4 objects (1 vertical, 1 horizontal and 2 angled lines). I rotated using Photoshop's smart snap but you can just rotate the line by 45 degrees. 360 / 8 = 45

[image]

Then select all of the layers and rotate them together. Because the angles are 45 degrees I will want to rotate the lines half of that which is 22.5. This is only to replicate how the bottom has a line just like github.

[image: turning the lines]

**How to create the individual parts**

Make sure all of the individual lines are flattened to one layer. Make a selection of that layer. Delete from the circle layer.

You can then use the pen tool to select one part of the circle and then copy -> paste into its own layer. Do this for the rest of the parts.

**Animation**

The animation is pretty basic. Just have a mid-tone gray. Have a 80% gray for the main line and then do a 70% gray for the line before it and then 60% before it. You can then just rotate the circle for each keyframe or just change the color values.

Comment: Thanks that helped me alot! I'm done now and it looks pretty smexy :)